# Fosuserbundle register validation not work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

When I register with an existing email, in the registerAction RegisterController `$form->isValid()` returns true despite that there is a constraint that exists in Fosuserbundle but I got an DBALException (An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO … ').

I created a bundle that inherits FOSUserBundle and MyUser entity inherits BaseUser and  I ovverided the RegistrationFormType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the validation to add an UniqueEntity constraint on the email field, you can add it directly to your Entity file (or use yml file, as you whish) :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

With the validation, the field will be checked when the `$form->isValid()` is called and will return an error if the email already exists in your database.

Comment: that work, I thought it was already described in fosuserbundle. thank you